# Cambié de servidor y ahora mi proyecto no funciona bien

Tags: servidor, dns, aws

Hace un día que cambié del servidor aws a otro, se apuntó la nueva direccion DNS y realizé la migración, sin embargo cuando lo probé me lanzó numerosos errores que no me aparecían en el aws y algunas funcionalidades dejaron de trabajar.

Ahora que he vuelto al aws sigue el problema, sé que hay que esperar horas, pero lo extraño es que he realizado cambios para comprobar que estoy en el servidor antiguo y si se notan, es decir, puedo verificar que he vuelto al aws, sin embargo la funcionalidad no es la misma.

¿Qué podría estar pasando?

Mi proyecto esta realizado de la siguiente manera, tengo dos directorios.

```
-Loupper-backend
-loupper-front
```

en uno he instalado laravel y desde alli manejo el backend, y el otro esta dedicado completamente al front end en el cual uso la libreria jquery, javascript y bootstrap, cuando el usuario entra, se carga automaticamente la carpeta 2, que es la de front, desde alli cada peticion que el usuario hace la manejo usando las peticiones ajax de jquery, como parametro url envio la url de mi dominio apuntando a la carpeta numero 1, en donde esta laravel y alli le envio la ruta y los parametros. ejemplo

```
url: "http://www.loupper.com/Loupper-backend/loupperapis/getPlanes",
success:...
```

El problema es que anteriormente todo estaba bien, pero ahora que he hecho el cambio, algunas de estas funciones me lanzan el internal server error, lo cual no se porque sucede ya que el codigo esta intacto, tampoco algunos efectos que se activaban cuando devolvia una peticion exitosa funcionan, es por eso que no entiendo cual podria ser el error.

Comment: Bienvenid@ a la comunidad. Por favor, ¿podrías crear un [MCVE](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Si no podemos reproducir tu problema no podremos ayudarte o el esfuerzo necesario para reproducirlo puede que nos haga abandonar tu pregunta. Tampoco sabemos si trabajas con node.js, python, php, etc. ¿Nos podrías facilitar la URL o al menos poner los mensajes exactos que te salen?

Comment: hola oscar, muy bien, editare el tema

Comment: @OscarGarcia ya he realizado la edicion, espero puedan ayudarme, te lo agradeceria un monton, saludos

Comment: ¿Qué internal server error es? ¿puedes mirar tu log de error del apache? Es probable que sea algún error de PHP, como alguna función que falte en el nuevo servidor. Sin ver el mensaje de error no puedo adivinar qué ocurre.

Comment: @OscarGarcia, ok debo revisar la consola del aws, el problema es que soy nuevo en ese servidor, las cosas no son tan faciles como en cpanel xd, pero he vuelto al servidor antiguo, en donde estaba antes, puede ser que el problema este en las redireccion del dns?, porque ya no he vuelto al nuevo hosting

Comment: Depende, como no sé qué dominio es no te lo puedo decir. Cambiar un registro DNS es inmediato y se almacena su valor anterior durante el valor de TTL que por defecto en bind9 (por ejemplo) es de 1 día, pero podría ser menos. En el servidor DNS de Microsoft es de una hora, y mi dominio tiene registros con solo 5 segundos de tiempo de vida, así que sin conocer el dominio no te puedo decir cuál es el problema.

Comment: Para saber el TTL por defecto de tu dominio puedes teclear (tanto en linux como en windows) `nslookup -type=soa <tudominio.com>` (sin `www` ni nada similar delante). También puedes usar `nslookup -debug <www.tudominio.com>` (ahora sí que debes poner las `www` o el dominio completo que uses para tu web). Allí verás el TTL restante del servidor DNS que tengas configurado en tu equipo. Si usas `nslookup -debug <www.tudominio.com> <ip de un servidor DNS de tu dominio>` te saldrá el TTL configurado y para obtener tus servidores DNS teclea `nslookup -query=NS <tudominio.com>`.

Comment: @OscarGarcia hola oscar, gracias por tus respuestas, he hecho lo que me dijiste y en el default ttl me aparece 1 dia, es eso lo que debo esperar para que todo vuelva a la normalidad no?

Comment: Ese es el tiempo MÁXIMO que debes esperar. Quien esté usando un DNS que no haya pedido previamente la resolución DNS de tu web mostrará la nueva web inmediatamente. Te recomiendo bajar el TTL a un máximo de 5 minutos durante la migración para poder aplicar cambios rápidamente, mejor si son solo 60 segundos.

Comment: @OscarGarcia Gracias por las respuestas, como puedo poner tu respuesta como la solucion al problema?

Comment: Si quieres redacta una respuesta con todo lo que hiciste y la marcas como solución. Te cedo los puntos de reputación. Si no, esta noche te redacto una respuesta con todos los detalles que hemos estado hablando.

Comment: Seguí tu consejo y redacté la respuesta :) un saludo y ¡espero que todo vaya bien en ese nuevo alojamiento!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Todo apunta a que tu cliente puede haber accedido al nuevo servidor pero algún servicio de tu servidor aún accede al viejo o viceversa.

Cambiar un registro DNS es inmediato y se almacena su valor anterior durante el valor de TTL que por defecto en bind9 (por ejemplo) es de 1 día, pero podría ser menos. En el servidor DNS de Microsoft es de una hora, y mi dominio tiene registros con solo 5 segundos de tiempo de vida.

Puedes hacer un `dig +nocmd +noall +answer www.google.es` para ver el tiempo que le queda a `www.google.es` para caducar en los servidores DNS que tengas configurado en tu equipo:

```
$ dig +nocmd +noall +answer www.google.es
www.google.es.      23  IN  A   216.58.211.195
```

Si haces un `dig +nocmd +noall +answer www.google.es @216.239.32.10` (`216.239.32.10` es la IP de uno de los servidores DNS del dominio de `google.es`) verás el TTL que tiene configurado dicho registro (300, 5 minutos):

```
$ dig +nocmd +noall +answer www.google.es @216.239.32.10
www.google.es.      300 IN  A   74.125.206.94
```

Para saber el TTL por defecto de tu dominio puedes teclear (tanto en linux como en windows y sin www ni nada similar delante del nombre del dominio):

```
nslookup -type=soa <tudominio.com>
```

También puedes usar (ahora sí que debes poner las www o el dominio completo que uses para tu web):

```
nslookup -debug <www.tudominio.com>
```

Allí verás el TTL restante del servidor DNS que tengas configurado en tu equipo.

Si usas:

```
nslookup -debug <www.tudominio.com> <ip de un servidor DNS de tu dominio>
```

Te saldrá el TTL configurado para ese registro.

Para obtener tus servidores DNS teclea:

```
nslookup -query=NS <tudominio.com>
```

> [@OscarGarcia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/18608/oscargarcia) hola oscar, gracias por tus respuestas, he hecho lo que
>   me dijiste y en el default ttl me aparece 1 dia, es eso lo que debo
>   esperar para que todo vuelva a la normalidad no? – [Felipe Castillo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/29237/felipe-castillo)

Te recomiendo bajar el TTL a un máximo de 5 minutos durante la migración para poder aplicar cambios rápidamente, mejor si son solo 60 segundos. Deberás esperar un día para asegurarte que nadie queda con un registro en caché con una TTL de un día, todos tendrán un TTL reducido y reaccionarán rápidamente a los cambios que hagas.

Cuando termines con la migración puedes volver a aumentar el tiempo.

Nota: éste es una adaptación/resumen de la conversación mantenida a través de comentarios.

Answer (score -2):

### ***Notas que debes tomar en cuenta:***

1.- Asegurate que los DNS introducidos sean correctos.

2.- Existe un tiempo limitado de 24 a 72 horas para que los DNS se propagen (eso dependiendo de cual sea tu proveedor de hosting)

3.- Asegurate que los DNS sean validos.

**¿Que pasa si ninguno de estos pasos te funciona?:**

- Pues tienes que contactar a tu proovedor de hosting

**¿Y si el proovedor de hosting no te brinda solución alguna?**

- Tienes una de dos: Volver a repetir los pasos para asegurarte o tendras que verte forzado a pedir un rembolso y contratar otro servicio

Comment: No existe un tiempo limitado de 24 horas a 72 horas para propagar un registro DNS. Si haces un `dig +nocmd +noall +answer www.google.es` verás el tiempo que le queda a `www.google.es` para caducar en los servidores DNS que tengas configurado en tu equipo y si haces un `dig +nocmd +noall +answer www.google.es @216.239.32.10` verás el TTL que tiene configurado dicho registro (300, 5 minutos).

Comment: me corrijo, algunos servidores de hosting aclaran que al cambiar los dns, USUALMENTE, SI ES QUE demoran mucho en propagarse, existe un tiempo entre 24 y 72 horas

Comment: Esa "propagación" de la que hablas parece que es al cambiar los servidores DNS. Ahora abriré una respuesta para explicarlo.